# How do they equate a scalar quantity and a vector quantity? What are the factors depend on $\vec F_{R,L}$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors

[Link to video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CfBeCHrQj_U&list=PLUl4u3cNGP61qDex7XslwNJ-xxxEFzMNV&index=41)
[image]

He said that Tension is a magnitude of the force acting from the left piece to right or force acting from the right piece to left (i.e. $|\vec{F}_{R,L}|=|\vec{F}_{R,L}|=T(p)$. So, Tension is a scalar quantity. Then in the later stage, he said that Force applied at $A$ is the tension at $A$ (i.e. $\vec F_A=T_A)$ and $\vec F_B=T_B$.

- How do they equate a scalar quantity and a vector quantity?

Now, I am adding one more question. What are the factors depend on $\vec F_{R,L}$?

Comment: I think words such as *tension* are being used interchangeably sometimes referring to a vector, sometimes to the magnitude of a vector. It should be clear from the context, and I wouldn't worry much about this.

Comment: What are the factors depend on $\vec F_{R,L}$? will it be equall to $\vec F_B$?